# nginx serve a specific directory for a specific location

Tags: nginx

I need for development purpose (not for production of course), to serve my logs that are in my folder /app/logs/.

So I've setup a configuration like this :

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server-name.com;
        error_log  /app/logs/error.log warn;
        access_log /app/logs/access.log compression;
        root /var/www;

        location /info/logs/ {
            alias /app/logs/;
            autoindex on;
        }

        location / {
          // others route working
        }
    }
```

But everytimes i try to access to something like /app/logs/django.log using http://server-name.com/info/logs/django.log, I get a 404 and not the file I asked for.

I've tried many things like chmod -R 755 the entire folder or setting the folder to the user nginx use (in my case for now root, I know it's bad), tried root or try_files but I just can't access it...

I've seen many topics here and there but can't find a clue...

Can you help me with this please ?

PS : I need the root /var/www at the beginning for others locations.

PS2 : I'm using a Docker based on Debian 9.

Comment: My bad, made a small mistake, I'm using http in the example since I'm in local.

Comment: Is there an entry in the error log?

Comment: No nothing in the entry log, which is strange...

Comment: Do you have SELinux enabled?

Comment: No I've not enabled SELinux in my Docker. I don't think this is a default setting on Debian 9, I've never used it before.

Comment: You should have mentioned earlier in you quest that you are using Docker, as this changes how this question is answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found my problem, I had a route like this :

```
# Any route containing a file extension (e.g. /devicesfile.js)
location ~ ^.+\..+$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

And I didn't know that despite the fact it was after the first location, it would be choosen over the other location...

Thanks for your help anyway !

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the standard NGINX Docker container, then the default configuration is to send the `Access` and `Error` logs to the Docker log collector. Not the standard log output for NGINX.

The result is that your log files are most likely going to:

`file/var/lib/docker/containers/<container id>/<container id>-json.log`
on the Docker Host. Where `<container id>` is the long-form version of the Container Id specified when the container was setup in the first place.

To get to the default log files you can do: `docker logs <container name>`

To find the `<container id>` you can do: `docker inspect --format '{{ .Id }}' <container name>`

If you want to customize where the log files go, then you need to create a helper Docker container that the log files can be written too.

Comment: I've checked, and I have my logs in the error.log of nginx also. I have no additionnal line with this particular configuration but if I try something else like root directive instead of alias, I have an error entry. So I don't think the problem comes from Docker.
I find it strange that nginx doesn't seem to enter the route.